# Can I make my custom class to be assignable from number in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for something similar to the implict constructor in other languages.
I want to assign a `MyNumber` variable via a single literal number such as:

```
class MyNumber {
  value:number
  constructor (value:number) {
    this.value = value
  }
}

const mynumner : MyNumber = 1
```

And I got an error: `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'MyNumber'.ts(2322)`

Can I make this type to be `number assignable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

TypeScript does not (currently) support no-arg [class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) [constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#constructor).